# jQuery: Proper Syntax For Prepending HTML

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and I'm trying to prepend some HTML. However, I keeping getting syntax error via DreamWeaver.

Here is my code:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
      $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $(".contentpadded").prepend($unoslider);

      var $unoslider = $('
        <ul id="unoslider" class="unoslider">
            <li><img src="templates/{$template}/img/cloud-hosting.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="templates/{$template}/img/green-hosting.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="templates/{$template}/img/trusted-partners.jpg" alt="" /></li>
        </ul>
        '),
      });
   </script>
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should concatenate the strings, also note that there is a redundant `,` in your code.

```
var $unoslider = $('<ul id="unoslider" class="unoslider">'+
                   '<li><img src="templates/{$template}/img/cloud-hosting.jpg" alt=""/></li>' +
                   '<li><img src="templates/{$template}/img/green-hosting.jpg" alt="" /></li>' +
                   '<li><img src="templates/{$template}/img/trusted-partners.jpg" alt="" /></li>' +
                   '</ul>');
$(".contentpadded").prepend($unoslider);
```

Note that you should first define the variable and then append it.

Comment: No, it did not work and I don't understand why. It's for a WHMCS template and it uses the smarty template system. So I had to wrap it in the {literal} tags, but that shouldn't make a difference right?

Comment: also, the ".contentpadded" is in a different template file(header), while the script is in the (home) file, but both are loaded to create the page. That shouldn't make a difference either should it?

Comment: @Xarcell What exactly doesn't work? You are using document ready handler, there should be no problem.

Comment: I experimented with putting the script in the same file as the element I wanted it to prepend to. It's still not working. The "unoslider" script works, but images are not loading, and it's not prepended.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
  var $unoslider = '\
    <ul id="unoslider" class="unoslider">\
        <li><img src="templates/{$template}/img/cloud-hosting.jpg" alt="" /></li>\
        <li><img src="templates/{$template}/img/green-hosting.jpg" alt="" /></li>\
        <li><img src="templates/{$template}/img/trusted-partners.jpg" alt="" /></li>\
    </ul>\
    ';
```

And the use the `prepend()` function.

Comment: You will need to add a \ (backslash) at the end of each line.

Comment: @BurningtheCodeigniter Is it fine now?

Answer (score 0):

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hVjDq/

There are two changes : 1)You string will have a syntax error as its not concatenated by "+".
2) You are prepending undefined variable, so you need to put the prepend statement after the html variable is ready.

Updated js code :

```
You missed "+" for concatenation..

var $unoslider = $('<ul id="unoslider" class="unoslider">'+
               '<li><img src="templates/{$template}/img/cloud-hosting.jpg" alt=""/></li>' +
               '<li><img src="templates/{$template}/img/green-hosting.jpg" alt="" /></li>' +
               '<li><img src="templates/{$template}/img/trusted-partners.jpg" alt="" /></li>' +
               '</ul>');
$(".contentpadded").prepend($unoslider);
```